# From an OEM side, how would someone be able to perform root cause analysis on application design?

Tags: datasheet, troubleshooting, block-diagram

Apologies for my ignorance on the subject but I am still relatively new in my career. This also might be a vague question as well. The only troubleshooting I've done on the silicon level was a dye-and-pry and used an x-ray to find a short circuit.

When I look at any datasheet for parts, there's always a block diagram for the chip's functionality. The block diagrams have smaller black box components that provide enhancements to the overall functionality of the chip.

Suppose you design the chip according to the application design and it fails. While finding the root cause, you pinpoint it down to the chip itself. How would you proceed further (without obviously talking with the supplier)?

Are there any common methods to troubleshoot further inside the chip? For instance you refer to the datasheet and look at the black box inside the block diagram and say, "The issue is definitely the reference voltage black box." I'm assuming such black box is protected by IP so it would difficult to know the exact layout of said black box.

Comment: When we brought our issue to the manufacturer, THEY xray-ed our failed parts to determine the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only time this has happened to me, the *only* way I found it was with grueling searches for the chip that pointed me to some sort of white paper about an erratum on certain versions of the chip.

Once I had that, I called the customer support line, and eventually got sent to a product engineer.  I described my symptoms, and I asked if it was due to the in silico error I read about.  It was confirmed.  He told me to request parts from my (reliable) vendor that were after a certain date code.

Note that this was all for an n=5 project, and an Analog Devices chip.

If I ever encounter similar issues with IC's bought from a reliable  vendor again, and I've eliminated every design issue and construction issue,  I'd probably start by searching for errata on the chip, and then if I don't find anything, follow up with the product engineer.  If I weren't using a reliable vendor, I'd reorder the part from a reliable vendor before trying to run down errata.

Comment: That's true! Almost forgot about the documents for "silicon errata". I wonder why suppliers don't update the errata in their datasheets. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @toolic -- very small quantity -- meaning I wasn't a huge customer, and still got great service from the product engineer.

Answer (score 11):

If you buy an IC, and it doesn't perform to specification, you don't trouble-shoot it, you throw it back at the supplier.

Even if the datasheet for the IC gives a block diagram, you can rest assured that it is for rough information only, telling you how the chip behaves, and it not intended to show you its implementation.

Certainly when talking with the manufacturer, it's worth saying that the reference black box output is the wrong voltage, or noisy, or not the advertised impedance, if that's the manifestation of the problem you're seeing at the pins.

I've come across one instance where a device did not meet advertised specs, and was unusable. I've had several cases where the behaviour we wanted was unspecified, but the manufacturer made a special to accommodate our tighter spec.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I was just curious on lower volume projects. Priority for your particular issue may not be as high as an OEM who probably provides products on a global scale.

Answer (score 2):

Got here; took the vendor's help to get out of it.

We were able to diagnose the problem of the malfunctioning CPU erasing its flash with a capturing oscilloscope. The problem was VBOR trigger happened too late, well below the CPU's voltage fault level.

A capturing oscilloscope is an expensive device that can read and store half a second of waveform for analysis. It's much faster than most CPUs and can in fact read the CPU's digital behavior as analog behavior and see the rise and fall of indiviual pins being changed between 0 and 1.

Further internal analysis found the CPU VBOR had four possible settings, two of which were literally insane. We were not able to determine why our CPUs were in the insane state by ourselves.

Initial-CPU flashing instructions (that ran before soldiering CPU to board) were incorrect. The result was the VBOR control bits were not the expected values. We received custom firmware from vendor to flash to CPU using the update method to correct the bad initial flashing (after which we would flash our own firmware back). One failed CPU had erased its update mechanism due to the fault so we had to graft on wires to reflash. This put the board into a state were it was continuously leaking power out a resister and heating up so we could only stay in that state (with the wires powered for reflash) for a few minutes, but it was long enough.

Due to this failure mode we were able to observe the actual behavior of a CPU in deep brownout. I can say with confidence the old wisdom handed down of have two copies of your variables is utterly incorrect. The actual behavior of CPUs in brownout is executing random jumps. We observed it executing unreachable code, including jumping past the logic that says whether or not to flash to the data eeprom, or even jumping into the update logic; and one CPU even jumped past the write protect logic and overwrite the update logic with something that wasn't update logic (and we couldn't tell what because it took out the means of telling what--see above for how we got this board working again).