# What is an "n=5 project"?

Tags: integrated-circuit

In the context of chip reliability "Note that this was all for an n=5 project, and an Analog Devices chip." What does "n=5 project" mean?

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/692876/359351

I would have made a comment asking for clarification but the reputation requirements blocked me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

\$n\$ is usually an integer that counts something.

In the context you come from, it means "A project with a total count of 5 pieces to be built".

The point the author of the answer there was making was: This was a project where only a small number of boards are made. This might shift the effort you want to take.

Comment: Although context often matters - there are plenty of mission critical $n=1$ boards out there.

Comment: absolutely, but the question is whether the component provider you're talking to (in the original question, that was a large IC company) is willing to say "oh, for a total of 5 pieces that you'll build using our components, we're able to invest a lot of support and potentially even R&D time", @JonCuster